# Get someone else's transaction history on authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I need to create system for aggregation some info from authorize.net. Transaction history, to be more precise. But i need to receive transaction history not from my account. PayPal has "third-party permissions" feature, which is perfect for my needs. What about it in authorize.net? How i can to see transaction history of other account (with his permission, if needed)? It's in principle possible?

Answer (score 0):

You use the transaction details API here: http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/  (more here: http://www.authorize.net/support/ReportingGuide_XML.pdf)

C# example:

```
//open a call to the Gateway
var gate = new ReportingGateway("YOUR_API_LOGIN", "YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY");

//Get all the batches settled
var batches = gate.GetSettledBatchList();

Console.WriteLine("All Batches in the last 30 days");

//Loop each batch returned
foreach (var item in batches) {
    Console.WriteLine("Batch ID: {0}, Settled On : {1}", item.ID,
                      item.SettledOn.ToShortDateString());
}

Console.WriteLine("*****************************************************");
Console.WriteLine();

//get all Transactions for the last 30 days
var transactions = gate.GetTransactionList();
foreach (var item in transactions) {
    Console.WriteLine("Transaction {0}: Card: {1} for {2} on {3}",
                      item.TransactionID, item.CardNumber,
                      item.SettleAmount.ToString("C"),
                      item.DateSubmitted.ToShortDateString());
}
```

To use it, the TransactionDetails API needs to be authorized on the merchant account:

1. Log into the Merchant Interface at https://account.authorize.net
2. Click Account from the main toolbar
3. Click Transaction Details API from the General Security Settings section
4. Enter your Secret Answer to your Secret Question in the field provided
5. Click Enable Transaction Details API

Comment: Thanks, but i should get and save someone else's credentials in my server for it. It's not secure. I want solution without transmitting credentials .

Comment: You need the credentials in order to tell Authorize.NET's server that you are authorized to use the API.  If you don't have credentials, it wouldn't be secure for them to send you anything.

Comment: @JenR is correct.  You might want to post a suggestion on the product ideas forum to add support for a Third Party or OAuth-type solution: http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Ideas/idb-p/ideas